# displaying single column and multiple rows from DB in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display single column from database in php. For eg. table contains users details like `users|userid|location` and I want all `userid` to be displayed.

I tried using this query :

```
select userid from users
```

But output is only first row.

How to get all rows but value of single column only?
Here is the code

```
<?php
 mysql_connect('localhost','root','******') or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db('data') or die(mysql_error());

 $q1 = mysql_query("Select * from user") or die(mysql_error());
 $no = mysql_num_rows($q1);
 $val=0;
 for( $i=1;$i<=$no;$i++)
 {
     $val=$val+1;
     echo"<br><br>";
 $q1=mysql_query("SELECT userid from user") or die(mysql_error());
 $q2 = mysql_result($q1, 0, 0);
 echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='$q2'/>";
 }
```

?>

Comment: Have you written any code for this?

Comment: I think your query is good. Did you put it inside a While() loop, and can you show some code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you left the loop out in php...

Comment: you can fetch data without any looping so it must display first row only.

Comment: You should put your Query result inside a loop. 

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Query_result)){
      echo $row['userid'];
    }

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

> To return an array consisting of all values of a single column from
>   the result set, specify PDO::FETCH_COLUMN. You can specify which
>   column you want with the fetch_argument parameter.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I got it right. Use

SELECT userid FROM tablename;